# Immutable.js OrderedMap get all elements between two keys

Tags: immutable.js

Given an OrderedMap, how can i get all elements between *startKey* and *endKey*?

I know OrderedMap got a slice() method, but this requires start and end to be index offsets, not keys.

Comment: Hi, did you find a better way than filter ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Filter](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedSet/filter). Start returning true when you see the start key and false when you see then endKey.

Comment: yes this is what I ended up doing, was hoping there was an easy way to get the offset of a key in the OrderedMap though.